# Any way to add a Swift Package weakly?

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager, xcframework

I'm adding a library via Swift Package Manager, the library's minimum required iOS version is higher than the minimum supported version of the app, previously I was using only the xcframework where I could set it as "optional" (ie. weak linking) and check if the version meets the minimum requirement before using the library. But is there any equivalent way to do this with Swift Package Manager?

Thanks!